# How to get current time elapsed percentage of today?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Im trying to get the current time elapsed percentage of todays time. It can be either javascript or php. How can I do that ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: $midnight = strtotime('00:00');
$epochseconds = gettimeofday(true);
$timeofdayseconds = $epochseconds - $midnight;
$timepercent = $timeofdayseconds/(60*60*24)*100;

Comment: Sometimes, I think `mattgemmell` has agents working for him who asks questions which redirect users to his site :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `Date` object and some arithmetic.  Convert the components of the current day into a equivalent unit (such as seconds), find their sum, and divide that by the number of that unit per day.

For example, the following is a solution in JavaScript.

```
var d = new Date();
var pctDayElapsed = (d.getHours() * 3600 + d.getMinutes() * 60 + d.getSeconds() + d.getMilliseconds()/1000)/86400;
```

Note that this approach piggybacks on the browser's localization.  Your result will depend on the browser's timezone.

Comment: I couldn't get this working. Does it have to be run on server ?

Comment: Sorry, I had one typo in the milliseconds portion of the code.  You should have no problem copying and pasting the code into a browser console, now.

Comment: Yeah, now it works. But there is a problem, the current time here is 1 am here but the code gives me percentage of "0.04291961805555556" ?

Comment: Yes, 0.042 means 4.2% of the day has passed.  That is accurate.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the current time to calculate the number of seconds that has elapsed today and then divide that by 86400 (the number of seconds in a day), and of course multiply that by 100 to get it from decimal to percent.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer in PHP:

```
$now=time();
$today=strtotime(date("m/d/Y"));
$seconds=$now-$today;
$day=24*60*60;//seconds in a day;
$percent=$seconds/$day*100;
```

OR

```
$hours=date('G')*60*60;
$minutes=date('i')*60;
$seconds=date('s');
$day=24*60*60;//seconds in a day;
$percent=($hours+$minutes+$seconds)/$day*100
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$timestamp = time();
$hours = intval(date("G", $timestamp));
$minutes = intval(date("i", $timestamp));
$seconds = intval(date("s", $timestamp));
$proportion_elapsed = ($hours * 60 * 60 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds) /
    (24 * 60 * 60);
printf("%0.4F of the day has elapsed.", $proportion_elapsed);
?>
```

This works as long as there are 86,400 seconds in a day, which may not be true due to Daylight Savings time or leap seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Round down to the beginning of the day by dividing the current time by 86400, then multiply that integer value by 86400. Then take the difference of the current time (in seconds of course) and then divide 86400 into it.  Lastly, multiply by 100.

Edit: mod works more efficiently

Pseudocode:

```
MidnightDays = (TimeInSeconds % 86400) * 86400;
Percentage = (TimeInSeconds - MidnightDays) / 86400 * 100;
```

Comment: ...or you could just use a mod instead of a div-then-multiply-then-subtract.